# Running Ubuntu with multiple monitors having a panel each

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, gnome, gnome-panel, nvidia-settings

I have just installed Ubuntu and I'm trying to set up a correct configuration for having multiple monitors.

I want the two monitors to have their own workspaces, yet the ability to drag a window from one monitor to the next.  I also want a separate panel (taskbar) for each monitor.

I have played around with `nvidia-settings` and tried the following different configs:

1. **Having both monitors `Use separate X screen"**
   A panel for each monitor but I couldn't drag windows from one monitor to the next
2. **Using TwinView**
   The ability to drag windows from one monitor to the next but only a single panel for the primary display

Now I want to have the above configurations combined.  Basically, as I stated beforehand, having a separate panel for each monitor and also the ability to drag windows across monitors.

Can anyone provide me with suggestions please?

Comment: The other answers did not help me with ubuntu 18. StackExchange doesn't let me answer because of reputation requirements, so I will leave my answer of another question with the same problem here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1257613/624299 Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Managed to fix it just now.

I did the following to create a new panel and move it to the secondary monitor:

1. Right click on existing panel and choose `New Panel`
2. Drag the new panel to the secondary monitor by <kbd>ALT + Drag</kbd>
3. Right click on your new panel and choose `Add to Panel`
4. From the list, choose `Windows List`

Wrote up a blog post about it [here](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/05/ubuntu-with-multiple-monitors-having.html).

Comment: The way I did it was to keep on adding panels until it added it to the other monitor. Then I removed the extraneous panels.

Comment: If you're on ubuntu-classic, you may need to use Super+Alt+RClick to access the "Add to Panel..." menu. ("Super" being the windows key in most cases)

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Drag method didn't work for my desktop, but there is another alternative.

1. Right-click the panel you'd like to move, and uncheck "Expand" in the properties
2. The panel will now have two 'handles' on each side - these can be used to drag the panel to a different monitor.
3. Re-check "Expand" in the panel properties once you have it where you'd like it