# Add panel to secondary monitor on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, gnome-panel

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx and I was wondering if it is possible to put a panel on a secondary monitor.

Here are methods I have tried which did not work:

1. Click and drag the panel from the primary monitor to the secondary monitor
2. Installing TwinView (couldn't find it)

Comment: appears to be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/140476/running-ubuntu-with-multiple-monitors-having-a-panel-each

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create the new panel as usual and then holding down <kbd>ALT</kbd> and drag it to the other monitor.

This <kbd>ALT</kbd>+drag method also works for moving windows around without needing to grab the top bar.

Comment: How do you do that thing with the ALT?

Comment: alt, click on ur panel with left, HOLD down the left button and drag.

Comment: Lol, I know that, I was wondering how you make the ALT look like it does in your answer.

Comment: Wait, nvm, know now, its the `<kbd>` HTML tag :P

Comment: One thing to be aware of with this: you need to drag the panel itself, not any of the icons or applets in it. Sometimes applets and icons will fill up the whole panel. I exposed a little bit of my panel by middle-clicking one of my launcher icons and dragging it to the side. Then I could ALT-Click or right click, or whatever in that little empty space left behind.

Comment: this still works on 11.10 gnome classic

Comment: Doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 13):

The <kbd>ALT</kbd> + Drag method didn't work for my desktop, but there is another alternative.

1. Right-click the panel you'd like to move, and uncheck "Expand" in the properties
2. The panel will now have two 'handles' on each side - these can be used to drag the panel to a different monitor.
3. Re-check "Expand" in the panel properties once you have it where you'd like it

Comment: Alt-drag also stopped working for me recently - seems to be https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=627732

Comment: alt + drag doesn't anymore, un-checking expand did the trick.