# How can I add panels to secondary monitor in Gnome 2.30.2 / Debian 6

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome-panel

I connected to my PC  second monitor, how can I add Gnome panels to it.

Method, described here ( [Add panel to secondary monitor on Ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/141372/add-panel-to-secondary-monitor-on-ubuntu-10-04) ) not works!

Answer (score 0):

I added a panel to my secondary monitor by:

1. Right Click on default panel> New Panel
2. Right click on the New Panel that appears> Properties
3. in the Panel Properties Box> Orientation drop down box
4. Select from the list> primary monitor options are listed first, followed by the second monitor options.
5. The options for all monitors are ALL listed in the Orientation drop down list.

Im using an IBM Open Client Red Hat Machine.

On my machine, when I minimize a program that is open on the secondary monitor, it still minimizes to the panel on the primary monitor and i'm not sure how to change that.